# Are tables still the preferred method of designing email templates?

Tags: email, html-table, formatting, standards

I am redesigning my company's email templates and I opted to code the basic structure from scratch rather than wrestling with what has been created in the distant past.

I ran into a problem designing the footer when I started testing the email in multiple mail apps. In researching the best way to fix it, I stumbled upon the factoid that you should design emails with table-based layouts. I was rather surprised as table-based layouts have been out of date for years.

In 2019 are tables still the go-to method for designing email templates in HTML?

Sources:
https://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/html-email-basics/
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2019/04/tables-in-html-emails-nesting/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on all of my experience with responsive emails, yes, they are still the way to go. There are frameworks to help with the process of creating the layouts though.

Check out: 
https://mjml.io/
https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/email-templates.html

There are others, but I've played around with both of these.

Comment: Thanks! This new revelation, that there are still corners of the internet where old bits of technology are not only the norm but also the best way to build things, is quite astonishing to me.

Comment: Email is a mess. There's really no semblance of a standard in emails. While the browser isn't perfect, it's much much better than email.